# Implementing recursive function for composite pattern?

Tags: java, oop, recursion, design-patterns

I have implemented a composite pattern with a composite class and a leaf class. The composite class contains an ArrayList of its children objects (which may be of type leaf or composite). Each class, both leaf and composite, have a boolean variable called 'satisfied'. My composite class can either be an 'and' or an 'or' class - if it's an 'and' class, it requires all of its children to be satisfied for it to be satisfied. If it's an 'or' class, it requires at least one of its children to be satisfied for it to be satisfied.

I am having trouble writing a recursive function 'isSatisfied' for the composite class to check whether all of its children are satisfied and therefore it would be too. It's recursive because if the composite object has children that are composite, it needs to check all of its children too etc. Here is what I've tried (it's incorrect). Any help would be appreciated.

```
public boolean isSatisfied(Component g) {
        if (type.equals('and')) {
            for (Component i : ((Composite) g).getChildren()) {
                if (i instanceof Composite) { //it's a composite
                    isSatisfied(i);
                } else { //it's a leaf
                    if (i.satisfied() == true) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        } else if (type.equals('or')) {
            for (Component i : ((Composite) g).getChildren()) {
                if (i instanceof Composite) {
                    isSatsified(i);
                } else {
                    if (i.satisfied() == true) {
                        return true;
                    } 
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What's issue you are facing? Can you elaborate a little more on the problem itself?

Comment: @pedrohreis I'm not sure how to implement this function recursively to go through every child in the composite pattern, what I have been trying is not working

Comment: I would suggest you go over this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to review how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: Try moving the `isSatisfied(Component g)` method to the `Component` interface, so that it becomes `g.isSatisfied()`. Then implement the method in each concrete child of `Component`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `satistifed()` is a property of the *component* (the root type in the pattern), then this property should be declared in the interface:

```
public interface Component {
    boolean isSatisfied();
}
```

Then the recursion happens as a consequence of calling the method on the children components:

```
public boolean isSatisfied() {
    if( type.equals("and")) {
        for( Component component : components ) {
            if( !component.isSatisfied() ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

(If a given `component` for one of the loop iteration happens to be a composite, the same method will be called again, hence, recursion).

While we're at it, the design can also be improved by avoiding the use of a string as a boolean marker (the part where `type.equals("and")`). If a given composite object is not going to change between AND-type and OR-type at runtime, consider having a separate `AndComposite` and `OrComposite` classes. If for some reason you want your composite to change their behavior at run-time, then I would use either a `boolean` or an enumerated type to distinguish them.